# node.js-using the same variable name at closure?

Tags: javascript

Can I use the same variable name at cosure?

```
function A(callback) {
    callback(2);
}

function B() {
    var test = 1;
    A(function(test){

    });
}
```

Is there any problem? memory leak? or any unexpected error?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Specifying `test` as a parameter to the anonymous function creates a new variable within that function scope, which "shadows" (overrides or hides) the `test` declared in the enclosing function.

Answer (score -1):

as i can understand you're using functional concepts, as i can see is valid, but if you please me this will be more clean and reusable:

```
function B(Func) {
    var test = 1;
    Func(function(test){

    });
}
function A(callback) {
    callback(2);
}
B(A);
```

hope help yuou